# Ошибка HTTP Status 404

Tags: java, jquery, eclipse

Ошибки в Console

```
окт 15, 2018 4:58:10 PM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener init
INFO: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: C:\eclipse\jre\bin;C:\Windows\Sun\Java\bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:/eclipse/jre/bin/client;C:/eclipse/jre/bin;C:/eclipse/jre/lib/i386;C:\PROGRA~1\Borland\Delphi5\Projects\Bpl;C:\PROGRA~1\Borland\vbroker\jre\Bin;C:\PROGRA~1\Borland\vbroker\Bin;C:\PROGRA~1\Borland\Delphi5\Bin;D:\oracle\product\10.2.0\client_1\bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Acronis\SnapAPI\;C:\Program Files\Aladdin\eToken\PKIClient\x32;C:\Program Files\nodejs\;C:\Users\rdv\AppData\Roaming\npm;C:\eclipse;;.
окт 15, 2018 4:58:10 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.SetPropertiesRule begin
WARNING: [SetPropertiesRule]{Server/Service/Engine/Host/Context} Setting property 'source' to 'org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:Appeal' did not find a matching property.
окт 15, 2018 4:58:10 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-9092"]
окт 15, 2018 4:58:10 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
окт 15, 2018 4:58:10 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFO: Initialization processed in 406 ms
окт 15, 2018 4:58:10 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
INFO: Starting service Catalina
окт 15, 2018 4:58:10 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/7.0.47
окт 15, 2018 4:58:10 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext resourcesStart
SEVERE: Error starting static Resources
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Document base C:\Users\rdv\workspace55555\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp3\wtpwebapps\Appeal does not exist or is not a readable directory
    at org.apache.naming.resources.FileDirContext.setDocBase(FileDirContext.java:138)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.resourcesStart(StandardContext.java:5055)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5235)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

окт 15, 2018 4:58:10 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
SEVERE: Error in resourceStart()
окт 15, 2018 4:58:10 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
SEVERE: Error getConfigured
окт 15, 2018 4:58:10 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
SEVERE: Context [/Appeal] startup failed due to previous errors
окт 15, 2018 4:58:10 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-9092"]
окт 15, 2018 4:58:10 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
окт 15, 2018 4:58:10 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 419 ms
```

Comment: В эксепшене сказано, что директория(`C:\Users\rdv\workspace55555\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp3\wtpwebapps\Appeal\`) не существует или у данной директории нет права на запись. Я привык верить эксепшенам. Я бы проверил есть ли такая директория и есть ли у неё права.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Данная ошибка ушла после добавления в Hibernate.cfg.xml следующей строки

```
<mapping class="domain.Tematspr"></mapping>
```